# Is d(sinx) and sin(dx) same?

Tags: calculus, differential

Is d(sinx) and sin(dx) same?
If it's not then is there a way to represent sin(dx) or for that matter any function f(x) where x is put to be some differential? Examples are most welcome if needed.

Comment: Where did you find those notations?

Comment: I may be thinking in the wrong direction but I wanted to compute for some problem sin(x+dx) - sinx where it is evident we will have a part of the expression sin (dx/2).

Comment: I think the reason for @Gae.S.'s comment was that these notations are not ordinarily used and thus need to be defined; furthermore, different definitions (in different contexts) can give you different answers. **One** fairly reasonable definition would say that $d(\sin x)=(\cos x)dx$ and $\sin(dx)=dx$.  **Another** would say $\sin(dx)=dx-(dx)^/3!+(dx)^5/5!-\dots$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly the way physicists write math you can use both expressions but they are not at all the same.  $d\ \sin(x)=\cos(x)\ dx$ is an expression you might use during a $u-$ substitution in an integral.  $\sin(dx)$ is the sine of a very small angle.  Based on the Taylor series, $\sin(dx)=dx$.  Based on your comment, if you have $\sin(x+dx)$ you can expand it as the sine of the sum of two angles, getting $\sin(x)\cos(dx)+\cos(x)\sin(dx)=$(if you only keep first order terms)$\sin(x)+\cos(x)\ dx$.  It represents how much $\sin (x)$ changes with $x$ depending on the value of $x$.

Comment: Thanks, it clarifies...Cheers!

Comment: $\sin(dx)=dx$ is not compatible with the definition of a differential.

Comment: The $\mathrm{d}\sin(x)=\cos(x)\mathrm{d}x$ is "physicist formalism" as well (I think it can be made formal in differential geometry), but a lot of mathematicians use it as well with the mentality "I could do it the correct way, but that's just too much mess".

Answer (score 0):

$\text{d}(sinx)=sin(x+\text{d}x)-sin(x)=\text{cos}(x)\text{d}x, dx \to 0$.

They aren't same always except when $\text{cos}x=1 \Rightarrow x=2mπ$.